# How do I download SCP and ssh on Cygwin?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, scp

I have downloaded Cygwin on windows 8 and use it for python scripts.
How do I get SCP and ssh on Cygwin without having to use WinSCP and Putty?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

When you run the Cygwin installer again to install new packages, you might notice that searching for "scp" produces no results.

It's actually part of the "openssh" package.

Answer (score 14):

Whenever you want to add new packages to Cygwin you run the setup.exe file again as if installing from scratch. The Cygwin setup can be downloaded [here](http://cygwin.com/install.html).
then search for the openssh package and install it. (remember you can do this even after having it installed, it'll just add what you need)

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, you do not need Cygwin to get Windows OpenSSH build.

You can use [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH), what is Microsoft official build of OpenSSH for Windows. On Windows 10 version 1803 or newer, you already have OpenSSH built-in. On older versions of Windows 10, it can be installed as an optional Windows feature. On older versions of Windows, you can just extract the `scp.exe`, `ssh.exe` and `libcrypto.dll` from a .zip ([latest release](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)), no installation is need.

---

Another way is to install [Windows subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about). The OpenSSH `sftp` and `ssh` are included.